# Loop through a string array but only print the elements with value?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, loops

I have a string array with 24 elements. These 24 represents a crate of soda. The user will first be asked what type and how many sodas the user wants to put inside.  Could be one, 20 or all 24.

I then want an option so that the user can print out whats inside the crate, I can do this with a for/foreach loop but I also get the empty ones printed out as well, even tho theyre blank on the console of course, but i either want ONLY the elements with values printet out, and not blank spaces, OR that the blank spaces says empty!

How would i best accomplish this?

Thanks!

*Edit, Thank you guys, lots of good anwsers I will try my way from here!

Comment: Could you, please, provide for everyone what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) to check whether a condition is met for certain elements of a collection.

```
using System.Linq;

var items = new string[] {"Cola", "", "Fanta", null, "Sprite", " "};

string[] nonEmptyItems = items.Where(i => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i)).ToArray();

foreach(var nonEmpty in nonEmptyItems) {
    Console.WriteLine(nonEmpty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say check to see if the array is empty, first. If it's empty, just don't print it.

Otherwise, simply build your "for" statement off of the length of the array, since I assume that you're adding sodas to the crate.

Even if you're using a foreach, you can still skip over the ones that don't have anything in them, just by checking their value, and skipping it if it's null/empty.

Answer (score 0):

How is this ?

```
 var values = new []
            {
                "v1", "v2", null, "v4"
            }.ToList();

            var withValues = values.Where(v => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(v)).ToList();
```

This will only return items with values.

To write out to the console do something like this

```
  values.Where(v => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(v)).ToList().ForEach(v =>
         {
             Console.WriteLine(v);
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `List<string>` that represents the specific user selection. As soon as the user selects one type of soda, add this type to your list.

E. g.:

```
List<string> crate = new List<string>;

...

string sodaselection = YourLogicForSelectingASoda();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sodaselection))
{
    crate.Add(sodaselection);
}
```

Comment: And how does this help OP to filter out empty entries?

Comment: @HimBromBeere this approach should show to the OP that is is better to just collect what is needed, instead of carrying around a fixed length array that may contain empty values

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] sodaCrate = new string[24];
foreach (string s in sodaCrate)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        continue;
    //do the stuff you want
}
```

This loops over your soda crate, checks if the entry is null or empty and if so it continues to the next.

Comment: Thank you! This one looked more simple (i'm very new to c#) and this worked like a charm!

Comment: Glad it worked! All the other options use something called LINQ, it's actually a very powerfull mechanism if used right so if you're ever looking on something interesting to learn you might want to check that out (though in this scenario the LINQ options are actually slightly less efficient). Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem

```
foreach(var data in items.Where(i => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i))) {
    Console.WriteLine(data);
}
```